# How to handle mouseover event for Raphael SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, mouseevent, raphael

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74YNb/10/) showing an example of what I'm trying to do. (I know it doesn't look right but it just needs some changes and that isn't the problem I'm facing :p ).

Im creating a pie chart using Raphael SVG, and the tooltip is also an svg element.

```
draw_tooltip(SVGpaper, this, 0);
```

is used to clear the tooltip.

The problem is I don't understand how to properly handle the mouseover event. On each event the tooltip needs to popup after clearing the previous tooltip, which I've tried to manage using the counter. But as is apparent from the fiddle, the mouseover event isn't smooth. Also, it stays even while shifting to other arcs and when it moves out of the pie.

Pleae suggest some solution!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem you are having, is that the new path/element that is being displayed for the tooltip, is then interfering with the mouse events, stopping the event from working. So Raphael can be a bit fiddly for mouse events, if dragging/moving. There's probably a couple of different ways around it. One may be handling events more globally and deciding what to do with them, or if you don't mind it, move the tooltip a bit further from the cursor location.

```
arc.mouseover(function (e) {
     x = e.pageX + 50;
     y = e.pageY;
     draw_tooltip(this, 1, display_text, x, y);

});
arc.mouseout( function(e) {
    popup.remove();
    popup_txt.remove();
    transparent_txt.remove();
});

arc.mousemove( function(e) {
    popup.attr({ x: e.pageX - 70, y: e.pageY - 70 });
    popup_txt.attr({ x: e.pageX - 25, y: e.pageY - 45});
    transparent_txt.attr({ x: e.pageX - 120, y: e.pageY - 120 });
});
```

}

I've also changed the path for a rect and a couple of bits, but the main thing is keeping the tooltip away from the event location. Otherwise I wonder if you may need to handle it from jquery or possibly to a handler thats attached to other elements than the arc, which will depend on the complexity of the page maybe. See if this solution will do.

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/74YNb/13/ (text alignment may need tweaking for all browsers)

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work on the fiddle. But I need to try other methods since the chart contains more complicated data. I will definitely keep your solution in mind!

Comment: I think that solution may work if there is more complicated data, as long as there isn't lots of objects overlaying each other. If you put up a new question with any other issues you have, I'm sure people will find a way. If you find you're doing this a lot, you may find it worth looking at the d3 svg project which is more geared towards handling charts and data and is quite mature.